# SUMMING a conditional statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query that gives me the sum of sales:

```
SELECT SUM(sales)
FROM 
    (SELECT sales FROM ...) combined
```

I now need to add a conditional subtraction based upon certain currencies that take out taxes, something like this, in pseudocode:

```
SELECT SUM(sales) - (SUM(sales) IF currency IN ('jpy', 'aud') * 0.05)
FROM 
    (SELECT sales FROM ...) combined
```

How would I create this conditional SUM or subquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might apply factor while summing:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN currency IN ('jpy', 'aud') 
                THEN sales * 0.95
                ELSE sales
            END)
FROM combined
```

[CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html) has two forms. This one checks whether boolean expression given after WHEN evaluates to true. If it does, it returns sales scaled down by 5 percent; if it does not, returns expression after ELSE. You can combine WHEN...THEN pairs. The first one that evaluates to true returns expression after THEN.

You might have done this as you suggested in a question, by substracting TAX from JPY and AUD, as follows:

```
SELECT SUM(sales) 
     - ifnull (SUM(CASE WHEN currency IN ('jpy', 'aud') 
                        THEN sales * 0.05
                    END), 0)
FROM combined
```

But it would not help the query in any way.

Comment: Thanks, this is actually the only one that works, though I don't have enough understanding of `CASE` to explain why!

Comment: @user1383058: You could view a `CASE` expression as an extended form of an `IF()` expression. Try [the manual on CASE expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) to learn more.

Answer (score 2):

Since there are only two alternatives, you could also use the [`IF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function:

```
SELECT SUM(sales * IF(currency IN ('jpy', 'aud'), 0.95, 1))
FROM combined
```

Another method would be to use implicit boolean conversion to `0` or `1` like this:

```
SELECT SUM(sales * (1 - currency IN ('jpy', 'aud') * 0.05))
```

The `currency IN ('jpy', 'aud')` boolean expression would implicitly convert to either `0` (when false) or `1` (when true), and that would result in either `sales * (1 - 0)` or `sales * (1 - 0.05)`, accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(sales) - case when (currency in ('jpy', 'aud') then (Sum(sales) * .05) else 0 end
```

(TSQL or mysql?)

Comment: Is this going to work? What if your sum contains jpy and usd currencies ?

Comment: It'll magically work ;) heh  Maybe better is   --   select sum(sales) - case when (currency in ('jpy', 'aud') then (select sum(sales) from table where currency in ('jpy', 'aud')) * .05 else 0 end.  Otherwise you'd have to walk towards a more complex inner join on itself to get a sum based on other values.

Comment: It will work only if you enclose case in sum(); this way it will force currency in `group by`.

Answer (score 1):

I think Alex is just about right. I've assumed that you can't mix jpy and usd etc so will need to group by currency, viz

```
SELECT currency, 
       SUM(sales) * (1 - CASE WHEN currency IN ('jpy', 'aud') 
                            THEN .05 -- 5% Tax
                         ELSE 
                            0 -- No tax
                         END)
FROM
(
    SELECT 'aud' as currency, 10.00 as sales
    UNION 
    SELECT 'usd' as currency, 20.00 as sales
    UNION
    SELECT 'gbp' as currency, 30.00 as sales
    UNION 
    SELECT 'jpy' as currency, 40.00 as sales
) salesdata
GROUP BY currency
```

Returns

```
aud 9.50
gbp 30.00
jpy 38.00
usd 20.00
```

Which Deducts 5% off the jpy and aud totals